# load jalali date from string in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to load `jalali` date from string and then, return it as `gregorian` date string. I'm using the following code:

```
def jalali_to_gregorian(col, format=None):
    if not format:
        format = "%Y/%m/d"
    gre = jdatetime.datetime.strptime(col, format=format).togregorian()
    return gre.strftime(format=format)

# register the function
spark.udf.register("jalali_to_gregorian", jalali_to_gregorian, StringType())
# load the date and show it:)
df = df.withColumn("financial_date", jalali_to_gregorian(df.PersianCreateDate))
df.select(['PersianCreateDate', 'financial_date']).show()
```

it throws `ValueError: time data 'Column<PersianCreateDate>' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d'` error at me.
the string from the column is a match and I have tested it. this is a problem from how spark is sending the column value to my function. anyway to solve it?

to test:

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([('1399/01/02',),('1399/01/01',)],['jalali'])
df = df.withColumn("gre", jalali_to_gregorian(df.jalali))
df.show()
```

should result in

```
+----------+----------+
|    jalali|       gre|
+----------+----------+
|1399/01/02|2020/03/20|
|1399/01/01|2020/03/21|
+----------+----------+
```

instead, I'm thrown at with:

```
Fail to execute line 2: df = df.withColumn("financial_date",    jalali_to_gregorian(df.jalali))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-6468469233020961307.py", line 375, in <module>
exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 7, in jalali_to_gregorian
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jdatetime/__init__.py", line 929, in strptime
(date_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Column<jalali>' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d''%Y/%m/%d'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to apply function to the column, not to the values inside the column.

The code that you have used: `spark.udf.register("jalali_to_gregorian", jalali_to_gregorian, StringType())` registers your function for use in the Spark SQL (via `spark.sql(...)`, not in the pyspark.

To get function that you can use inside `withColumn`, `select`, etc., you need to create a wrapper function that is done with `udf` function and this function should be used in the `withColumn`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
jalali_to_gregorian_udf = udf(jalali_to_gregorian, StringType())
df = df.withColumn("gre", jalali_to_gregorian_udf(df.jalali))
>>> df.show()
+----------+----------+
|    jalali|       gre|
+----------+----------+
|1399/01/02|2020/03/21|
|1399/01/01|2020/03/20|
+----------+----------+
```

See [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html) for more details.

You also have the error in the time format - instead of `format = "%Y/%m/d"` it should be `format = "%Y/%m/%d"`.

P.S. If you're running on Spark 3.x, then I recommend to look to the [vectorized UDFs (aka, Pandas UDFs)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#pandas-udfs-aka-vectorized-udfs) - they are much faster than usual UDFs, and will provide better performance if you have a lot of data.